# Setting up references in .NET Web Forms with Masterpage

Tags: asp.net

This might be something simple for many but for me it's still a huge confusion web. I'm tired of placing references everywhre on master page and normal pages so I'm just going to ask here. I have a project which uses plugins and I want to set references on Master Page so the normal pages can see those references so I don't need to place them on each page one by one. Question is, I'm doing this but why does it not work?

Example

This is My Master Page

```
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="AdminLTE/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="AdminLTE/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="AdminLTE/bower_components/Ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="AdminLTE/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="AdminLTE/bower_components/datatables.net-bs/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="AdminLTE/dist/css/skins/skin-blue.min.css" />

 <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

</head>

<body>

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PageBody" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

<script src="AdminLTE/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script src="AdminLTE/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="AdminLTE/bower_components/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="AdminLTE/bower_components/datatables.net-bs/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>     
<script src="AdminLTE/dist/js/adminlte.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/MasterPage/main.js"></script>

</body>  
</html>
```

And in another page i'm using jquery table where I set the DataTable to Table ID with

```
 <script>
     $(function () {
         $.noConflict();
         $("#tblRegistos").DataTable();
     });
</script>
```

And still it says it doesn't recognize DataTable as a function. Script references are in order by the way because it works on the page but not if on master page

EDIT

I just tried to put scripts in the Head of master page and it worked but i tried to avoid this because I read that it's a bad practice to do...

Comment: It's because your script tags in the child pages will be rendered before your files.

Comment: How do i solve this problem?

Comment: I've added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your script tags in the child pages will be rendered before your files. Add the js content of your script tags to .js files and reference them on the master page after main.js.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/MasterPage/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/OtherPage/otherPage.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, i think with this example i finally understand how it works. I guess it was executing the datatable function on the page before reaching the reference since the content place holder was rendered first before reaching the end of master page. Everything makes sense now, I put the function on a js file and did as your example

Comment: Yes you were calling .DataTable before the method had been loaded by the browser :)